# Analysis of Algorithms | Big-O Notation

Tags: asymptotics

My question is related to the space-time complexity to find the values of n and c by considering this question.

[image]

[image]

AS we have seen that there are multiple solution for the above equation is possible. But I am confused which one we have to consider.

**In solution1: nO = 5 and c = 101 ; this states that we are considering the input after the size of 5 and c = 101 will give us the graph of c(g(n)) closer to f(n).**

**In solution2: nO=1 and c=105 ; states that we are considering all input but our graph is more away than f(n)**

But Big(O) always states that we have to consider the graph whose  rate of growth g(n) which is greater than or equal to given algorithms rate of growth     f(n).

So according to me the solution1 is best Although we are losing the five inputs but we are closer to our f(n)

Or there will be another logic for this ?

Comment: You can choose whichever parameters you want. The point of big O notation is to hide these details from you. We just don't care about them.

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: @Raphael I want to study data structure and Algorithm from basics using C language can you suggest some resources where I can learn these topics deeply ?

Comment: Since your query is hardly original, I suggest you use Google and the search on this site. You can also hit [chat] provided you have a couple of reputation on the SE network.